# How to get values from one method o another

Tags: java, return

I have my code but i can't get my variable stick() or scrapMetal() to carry over. Its set up to give you a random amount, but i can only reutrn one value. What should i do? I tried declaring the variable outside of the method, but that didnt work either!
Code:

```
public void turnOne(){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("You realise that in order to survive, you must leave the planet.");
    System.out.println("You start to look around, thinking of how you could repair your ship.");
    System.out.println("<Press 1 to scavenge, 2 to move north, 3 for east, 4 for south, or 5 for west>");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int yesno = input.nextInt();
    int drops = ((int)(Math.random() * 5));
    int stick = 0;
    int scrapMetal = 0;
    if (yesno == 1){
        System.out.println("You start to scavenge your surroundings.");
        if (drops == 4){
            System.out.println("You found sticks!");
            stick = ((int)(Math.random() * 6));;
            System.out.println("You now have " + stick + " sticks!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You were not able to find any sticks.");
        }
        drops = ((int)(Math.random() * 9));
        if (drops == 7){
            System.out.println("You found some scrap metal!");
            scrapMetal = ((int)(Math.random() * 4));
            System.out.println("You now have " + scrapMetal + " pieces of scrap metal!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You were not able to find any scrap metal.");
        }
        System.out.println("What would you like to do now?");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create static class like:

```
static class MyParameters {
    int stick;
    int scrapMetal;
    MyParameters(int stick, int scrapMetal) {
        //set variables
    }
    //getters
}
```

Now from your method `turnOne` you could just return an instance of MyParameters (instead of void) and access both the values using getter like:

```
MyParameters parameters = turnOne();
System.out.println(parameters.get...);
```

Answer (score 0):

For variables to be shared amongst for more than one method, the variables 'stick' and 'scrapMetal' should be coded outside of those methods but inside the class those methods lie in.

Example:-

```
public class YourProgram
{
    int stick;
    int scrapMetal;

    //Maybe Some constructors here...

    public void turnOne()
    {
        //DO NOT declare variables stick and scrapMetal here again.
        //Your above code goes here....
    }

    public void someOtherMethod()
    {
        //DO NOT declare variables stick and scrapMetal here again.
        //Some code goes here which uses stick and/or scrapMetal variables...
    }

    //Probably some more methods and other code blocks go here...
}
```